# Using Shell and Cmd

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

'Hello All, I am very new to VBA macro actually. I need help to create a macro which should open command prompt or powershell and then perform ping www.yahoo.com -t whenever user run that macro enabled doc file.
I am not able to create this. I tried below on windows 10 host.

```
Sub openBatch()
Call Shell("cmd ping yahoo.com -t", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see `Shell()` as an equivalent of  the Start > Run... tool in Windows or a `call` command in a command shell. In both cases, `cmd ping yahoo.com -t` would not work. You can either use `ping yahoo.com -t` or `cmd -c ping yahoo.com -t`.

So your code would become:

```
Sub openBatch()
Call Shell("ping yahoo.com -t", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest that you instead offer `cmd /c` as most Windows commands use the forward slash to precede their options. Some commands are interchangeable and some, like `ping` do use `-`. If you type `help cmd` in a Command Prompt window, it should confirm my suggested syntax.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmipicmp/win32-pingstatus

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From win32_PingStatus where address='www.yahoo.com'")
For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox "Status " & objItem.statuscode & " - Time " & objItem.ResponseTime
Next
```

Programmers don't shell to user's commands as its very unprofessional. The above is VBScript/VBA/VB6 code. If a user's command can do then so can you.

WMI has a command line interface as well. You can get help on Win32_PingStatus by typing in a command prompt

```
wmic path win32_pingstatus get /?
```

Comment: Mark, do you know, in this case, if there is any efficiency/benefit in `Select`ing only what is required? i.e. `Select StatusCode,ResponseTime From` instead of `Select`ing everything `Select * From` and effectively throwing away, all items except for `StatusCode` and `ResponseTime`.

Comment: The class would have all the data filled in. So probably not. It is a database query to return a subset of a database so maybe save a few bytes in the recordset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mark. For me using the asterisk seems a little inefficient, if only a single or minimal sub set is actually required. I have always selected only what is required for my subsequent commands, but have never thought to verify whether my approach was worthwhile.